# How do I launch iBooks e-reader programmatically on iPad?

Tags: ipad

Just like `UIApplication.openURL`.

Is there an API to launch iBooks with an ISBN?

Comment: Hi Sujee, 
Seems you have solved the problem.

Do you know how to open a local file which I have already download to my App's application directory in iBook?

URL to my file looks like this:
file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/51CC125E-5499-4E68-BF07-91DFFFC03B7D/Library/Application%20Support/82/index.pdf

so I expect I can call iBook to open my PDF using URL:
ibooks://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/51CC125E-5499-4E68-BF07-91DFFFC03B7D/Library/Application%20Support/82/index.pdf 

End up it open iBook app only, but not my pdf file.

Anything's wrong in my URL??

Comment: @Bowie maybe it is to late, but you could try UIDocumentInteractionController

Answer (score 17, accepted):

iBooks registers the `itms-books:` and `itms-bookss:` URL schemes, so you can launch iBooks programmatically, but the actual URL might not be an ISBN.

Comment: Thanks KennyTM.  where can I find more documentation on this, specially the URL format ?

Comment: @linuxlover: If you have the iPad, try to open iBooks and copy a link in the iBookstore. If you see ISBN in the link, then it's good. Otherwise, we can only say the URL format is undocumented.

Comment: Hi not sure about SO etiquette on an old question like this but is any further info available for this? Have launched  url://itms-books on iPad and it opens iBooks to store. Cannot figure out url for specific book or PDF. Have also tried using md5sum as filename based on this link: http://www.gabrielgambetta.com/?p=40

Comment: @KennyTM what if the pdfs are placed in my code lets say i do file = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPdfPathiPhone"];
            NSString *stringURL = @"itms-books://";
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[stringURL stringByAppendingString:file]];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
will that work? and which scheme to prefer?

Comment: hi kennytm, indeed it opens ibooks, thanks. But it doesn't download the file. Any solution?

Answer (score 9):

iBooks

```c
NSString *stringURL = @"itms-books:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

NSString *stringURL = @"itms-bookss:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: Anyone know why there's ibooks and ibooksS... was that a typo in early versions?

Answer (score 6):

For your info, folks: all it takes is to add the `itunes.apple.com` URL, the same you can find in iTunes when browsing the BookStore on the Mac, but replace `http` with `itms-books` and b00m, you have it! Example

```
itms-books://itunes.apple.com/de/book/marchen/id436945766
```

or

```
itms-books://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewMultiRoom?fcId=510054265&s=143443
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Guess the question is still looking for a perfect answer.

There is a book say Swift Programming in iBooks.

Is there a way to directly open this book, instead of first opening the iBook application then choosing required book.

```
NSString *stringURL = @"itms-books:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

This piece of code opens the iBook from within the app, but what about opening a particular book.