# Open iBooks from an iPad application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I launch iBooks e-reader programmatically on iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594321/how-do-i-launch-ibooks-e-reader-programmatically-on-ipad)

I'm creating an application for a client. The iPad will be pre-loaded with a ebook that we will be creating ourselves. This ebook will not be available in the bookstore, but will be preloaded via itunes.

- Is it possible to open the iBooks application from my application, via some URL schema?
- Is it then possible to link directly to our pre-loaded book from our application?

Any info would be appreciated.

Cheers

Niall

Comment: No this isn't a duplicate - I wanted to open a specific pre-loaded ebook / pdf, not one that has been bought via the iBookStore.

Answer (score 4):

iBooks registers the `itms-books:` and `itms-bookss:` URL schemes.  One would hope that passing an ISBN as the url would launch the correct book in the store, but I am not sure if it does.

Comment: You have to pass a URL -- See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594321/how-to-launch-ibooks-e-reader-programmatically-on-ipad/2596002#2596002 as well as http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/ibooks

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if there's a solution for native apps here: http://andycodes.tumblr.com/post/738375724/ios4-sdk-opening-pdfs-in-ibooks

We have a similar issue, and working on implementing solution above.
 We currently have hacky version that linked from shared dropbox folder to open in browser, and then asked user to select "Open in iBooks" (as described here): http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4227

Does the trick, and prevents us from having to preload on 200 iPads but lots of room for user error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [list of url schemes in iPhone OS](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes). Looks like you're out of luck of iBooks.

Comment: Looks like that hasn't been updated yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could start a mini-webserver with your application and open a URI like `itms-books://localhost:1234/my.epub`

Answer (score -1):

In short, no. iBooks won't be able to load anything that comes in your application's bundle.

Comment: Question states that book will be preloaded into iBooks by iTunes, not out of the bundle.