# How to launch specific iBook from app?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ibooks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I launch iBooks e-reader programmatically on iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594321/how-do-i-launch-ibooks-e-reader-programmatically-on-ipad)

While this question is answered on how to launch iBooks from an app
[open iBooks from my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358945/open-ibooks-from-my-app)

But I need to launch a specific iBook from an app.  It should open iBooks and then open the specific iBook.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *stringURL = @"itms-books:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

NSString *stringURL = @"itms-bookss:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

As explained on: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes under the "iBooks" entry.