# Is there a URL Scheme for iBooks?

Tags: ios, ibooks

I have an app that would like to be able to jump to a specific pdf or iBook in iBooks?  Is there a URL scheme for doing this?  The latest copy of the [Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) was last updated in 2010.

Comment: check these links

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594321/how-do-i-launch-ibooks-e-reader-programmatically-on-ipad][1]


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358945/open-ibooks-from-my-app][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594321/how-do-i-launch-ibooks-e-reader-programmatically-on-ipad
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358945/open-ibooks-from-my-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your desktop just copy URL from Books section in iTunes (use "Copy Link" option) and this will you give Apple iTunes link to given book with regular URL with http:// protocol - no hackery-pottery (with undocumented protocols schemes in 5.1OS) and it just works.

regards,

Peter