# how to open epub file in iBook from app

Tags: ios, swift, epub, ibooks

How to download epub file and open it in iBook in my swift app. 
I tried to handle it like this:

```
var urlAt = NSURL(string: epubFileUrl);
    if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(urlAt!)){
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(urlAt!);
    }
```

The app opened safari, downloaded my file and suggested me "how to open this file"

[image: safari download result]

My question - can I download my epub file in my app, and open (or suggest to open) it in iBooks app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9726517