# Opening iBook File on iPad from HTML Link

Tags: html, ios, ipad, ibooks

This is a bit of a strange question, but I have a client who's employees will be accessing an intranet site using company provided iPads. All of these iPads will have an book loaded into iBooks. They want us to link to that book from the intranet site. I can't find a way that this can be done. Does anyone know how it might be done? If not, do you know of a way that we can link to the iBooks application so that it will launch and at least give the user the menu of iBooks available on the device? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just link to the "filename.books" file?

Comment: Hi unclesol, Have you solved the problem yet?
I just encounter the same situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open iBooks to a specific book now by including the assetid of the book you want to open. Example:

```
ibooks://assetid/1396541327
```

Details available on the Apple.com website - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202929

Answer (score 1):

You can open directly to iBooks by using the url:

```
<a href="itms-books:">My Link</a>
```

This is a possible duplicate of [How do I launch iBooks e-reader programmatically on iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594321/how-do-i-launch-ibooks-e-reader-programmatically-on-ipad/)

Comment: In testing this, it seems like it wants to open the iTunes store. I actually don't want to open the store, but would prefer to open the locally stored book - and if that's not possible, I would like to open the iBooks application.

Comment: Also, oddly enough, whenever it does attempt to connect to the iTunes store it says "could not connect to the iTunes store"