# How to open the iBook file without use the third party apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, ibooks, uidocumentinteraction

I want to open the **iBook** file in my device without use the third party apps like **iBook App**.I have read many articles and suggests use of **UIDocumentInterectionController class.**

See the SO answer [How to open a file on iBooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577165/how-to-open-a-file-on-ibooks?rq=1)

When I use UIDocumentInterectionController class with demo app, it launch the iBooks Appliaction. But i want to open the file without third party app.

If I have use **itms-books:** at the beginning in the url , It's not work in IOS 7.

Please help Me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are opening a aPub file it might work to use some ePub component.

Native iBook files are not support by iOS and there for [`UIDocumentInterectionController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) will not be able to display the file and open iBooks.

[QuickLook](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010413-SW1) only supports:

- iWork documents
- Microsoft Office documents (Office ‘97 and newer)
- Rich Text Format (RTF) documents
- PDF files
- Images
- Text files whose uniform type identifier (UTI) conforms to the public.text type
- Comma-separated value (csv) files

Comment: rckoenes,Super answer