# In iOS, selected cell should move to top portion without any disturbance in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I asked one doubt yesterday, [here at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329857/in-ios-selected-cell-should-move-to-top-portion-in-uitableview)

In that I got 4 answers. Those 4 answers helped me to solve my problem. But now in same scenario, I have another issue. When I open 3rd cell it opens in same place.

[image]

I want to close that cell, so I press the button then it closes successfully. but the issue is after closed, it goes to top position.

[image]

How to solve this issue. I think I did mistake in calling this method `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`. In my previous question, (Refer the 1st line link) I changed a single line in below described method.

```
- (void)method_Expand:(UIButton*)sender
{
    int_SelectedIndex = sender.tag;
    [tbl_CalendarList scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:int_SelectedIndex inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Selected Button : %ld",(long)int_SelectedIndex);
    if ( int_TempSelectedIndex != int_SelectedIndex)
    {
        int_TempSelectedIndex = int_SelectedIndex;
    }
    else
    {
        int_TempSelectedIndex = -1;
    }
    [tbl_CalendarList reloadData];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you call your `method_Expand` - each time the cell is tapped?

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Just see my previous Question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329857/in-ios-selected-cell-should-move-to-top-portion-in-uitableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329857/in-ios-selected-cell-should-move-to-top-portion-in-uitableview) your `method_Expand:` is called when custom in-cell button is tapped. Try changing your code to:

```
- (void)method_Expand:(UIButton*)sender
{
    int_SelectedIndex = sender.tag;

    NSLog(@"Selected Button : %ld",(long)int_SelectedIndex);

    if ( int_TempSelectedIndex != int_SelectedIndex)
    {
        int_TempSelectedIndex = int_SelectedIndex;

        [tbl_BlogList scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:int_SelectedIndex inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        int_TempSelectedIndex = -1;
    }
    [tbl_CalendarList reloadData];
}
```

This way tapped cell will scroll to top only when it is being expanded and not when it is being collapsed.

EDIT: there is another way

```
- (void)method_Expand:(UIButton*)sender
{
    int_SelectedIndex = sender.tag;

    NSLog(@"Selected Button : %ld",(long)int_SelectedIndex);

    if ( int_TempSelectedIndex != int_SelectedIndex)
    {
        int_TempSelectedIndex = int_SelectedIndex;
    }
    else
    {
        int_TempSelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    [tbl_CalendarList reloadData];

    if (int_TempSelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_thread(), ^{
            [tbl_BlogList scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:int_SelectedIndex inSection:0]
                                atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                                        animated:YES];
        });
    }
}
```

Source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16071589/653513)

Comment: Its fine. but 3rd cell is in open state. now i select 5th cell, now that cell is not going to top position. In this same question i add that image at last.

Comment: oops - the scrollTo... line should follow the one setting the index. i changed the answer.

Comment: i understand ur answer. my question is, one cell is expanded. am not collapsed it, now i want to open another cell. at that time this issue is raised.

Comment: Ya tried it. but newly selected cell is not coming to Top Position.