# How to get device's pdfs and other files in iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdocumentdirectory

I want to import data from my iPhone to my application . up till now i have successfully imported Photo Library and music , but i also want to import pdf and other documents in my iOS app? How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSFileManager *mgr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

    NSArray *allFiles = [mgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundlePath   error:NULL];
    for (NSString *fileName in allFiles)
    {
        if ([[fileName pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"pdf"])
        {
            NSString *fullFilePath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
            // fullFilePath now contains the path to your pdf file
         //   DoSomethingWithFile(fullFilePath);

            NSLog(@"file: %@",fullFilePath);

        }
    }

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"" withExtension: @"pdf"];

    NSLog(@"File: %@",url);
```

Comment: Sir i need PDF and document of my devices not of my project directory , like if i want any photo to import in my app it open photoLibrary and i pick item from there. same if a pdf is running on ibook that i sync through i tunes i want that in my app to import

Comment: May be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594321/how-do-i-launch-ibooks-e-reader-programmatically-on-ipad

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in iOS 8 (I haven't checked 9 though). You can't even enlist your app (adding corresponding URL schemes) in the sharing menu of iBooks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to associate your app with the PDF types which you want to open. You can do this by adding some parameters to your Info.plist.

There's a well-answered post which explains this:

[How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

You should also consider reading Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1) and a blog [post](https://ikiwitech.com/2017/05/21/how-to-associate-your-swift-app-to-open-a-pdf-from-gmail/) written by me.